# using ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer does not resolve default values for @Value

Tags: spring-boot

When I am using:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { DmiVehicleRTExportConfig.class },
  initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

my integration tests are failing as properties such as:

```
${oauth2client.prematureTimeout:600}
```

are not getting default value of 600.

This is resolved through using: `SpringApplicationConfiguration` but I want to use `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class` instead of `SpringApplicationConfiguration`.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem.

```@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class, classes = { DatabaseConfig.class }```

Is not loading my yaml for the Config glass @Value injection...

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.class` needs to be added:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { DmiVehicleRTExportConfig.class, 
                           PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.class },
initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

Spring team has just added a note about that:

> Using ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer alone won’t provide support for @Value("${…​}") injection. Its only job is to ensure that application.properties files are loaded into Spring’s Environment. For @Value support you need to either additionally configure a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer or use @SpringBootTest where one will be auto-configured for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in JUnit tests also when using

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration
```

I solve this by adding a class with a 'static void main()' method to the configuration classes :

```
@Configuration
public class SpringEmptyApplication{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(SpringBootEmptyApplication.class);
  }
}
```

I put this class as first to the list of configuration classes like

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {     
SpringBootEmptyApplication.class,
DmiVehicleRTExportConfig.class 
})
```

This works perfect for me.

If you want to avoid

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration
```

you can try

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class ...
```

This is how @SpringApplicationConfiguration itself is annotated, may be this loader can fix the problem, did not try...